# Name of obscuring element changes ID

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio, selenium

I'm writing a testcase in Selenium using Visual Studio.

In several testcases I need to wait for a temporary obscuring element to disappear. The problem is that the name of this element changes its "number ID".

This is the name of the obscuring element:

```
.mat-snack-bar-container.ng-tns-c36-13.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-state.snack-bar-success.mat-snack-bar-top.ng-star-inserted
```

The part that always changes is this part: **36-13**

I'm waiting for it to disappear like this:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector(".mat-snack-bar-container.ng-tns-c36-13.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-state.snack-bar-success.mat-snack-bar-top.ng-star-inserted")));
```

Instead of me writing 9999 lines of code to cover every ID of this element. Is there a way to just write one line of code that looks for this ID in a scope between 00-00 to 99-99?

Comment: Can you give us the element HTML?

Comment: Is that a chain of classes? if so, you can simply leave out the offending class - the part `.ng-tns-c36-13` - unless there are more elements that have the other classes.

Comment: @Valga Is this what you are looking for: `<snack-bar-container class="mat-snack-bar-container ng-tns-c72-68 ng-trigger ng-trigger-state snack-bar-success mat-snack-bar-top ng-star-inserted"> `?

Comment: @MrLister Not sure what a chain of classes is. The obscuring element appears as a green box telling the user that the last action performed was successful.

I'm guessing that, since there a more than one action that can be successful, they gave these elements a different ID for each successful action.

Comment: Try this CssSelector: `"snack-bar-container[class*='mat-snack-bar-container ng-tns-c][class*=' ng-trigger ng-trigger-state snack-bar-success mat-snack-bar-top ng-star-inserted']"`

Comment: @Valga This did not work. Does the '*' mean all classes?

Comment: *= means everything that has certain value inside an attribute, example: [class*="value"] selects all the elements that contains "value" in its class attribute, but it's strange, i tested this CssSelector here and it worked...

Comment: oh, it didn't work because stackoverflow broke the line causing a wild space to appear after the first class filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to use begins with and ends with in css.

```
[class^='mat-snack-bar-container ng-tns-c'][class$='ng-trigger ng-trigger-state snack-bar-success mat-snack-bar-top ng-star-inserted']
```

The below code will wait until the element invisible.

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.CssSelector("[class^='mat-snack-bar-container ng-tns-c'][class$='ng-trigger ng-trigger-state snack-bar-success mat-snack-bar-top ng-star-inserted']")));
```

Comment: This did not work. Not sure why. What are the ^ and $ used for? (I tried without them but it did not help)

Comment: `^` stands for `starts with` and `$` stands for `ends with`. Check with my updated answer.

Comment: The updated solution worked! Thanks! My only question left is: What is the proper format when using CSSselector?

Some say you have to use dots in the begining and between every space. Like this: `".ng-trigger.ng-trigger-state.snack-bar-success.mat-snack-bar-top.ng-star-inserted"`

But in your solution you did not use dots and it still worked. So I'm a bit confused on that minor part.

Comment: If you are using only entire class then you have to use the `.` approach. And if you want to use part of the class in your css selector (like in our example) then you have to use the exact attribute value rather replaying spaces with `.`.